# 400 Bad Request when trying to access Twitter API 1.1 on webpage

Tags: json, api, twitter

I'm trying to update this Tweet Scroller I built on a client's homepage.

www.xsp.com

I'm using the following line to access the api:

```
var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + username + '&count=' + limit + '&callback=?'; //NEW API CALL V1.1';
```

Where username and limit are custom set variables.

This is what I'm getting in my Firebug console:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=XSPGlob…&count=5&callback=jQuery19005188902916852385_1358892149117&_=1358892149118 400 (Bad Request)
```

I've checked the Twitter documentation. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Does anyone have any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume you're accessing the API URL correctly since I can't check it right now (lol proxy), but it looks like the username has a weird character in it that might need to be escaped by some URL encoding characters?

It looks like you're using javascript, which I'm not too familiar with, but in java if indeed the URL was bad, an exception would be thrown.  Is there no javascript compiler that can check for stuff like this?